# google spreadsheet lookup query for whole sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

[image: my spreadsheet]

this is my spreadsheet, i want to create a new sheet with the following aggregation: I have a table with date column and sum column. in the sum column I want to sum the quantity of each row the date appears. For example, for 7/5/2015 it will sum B4, B5, B10, B11, B15, B17, B22, B25, B29.

**EDIT: My range should contain the whole sheet, from d to infinity and from 2 to infinity and I'm using google spreadsheet**

I tried this formula, but it returns error: 
       =LOOKUP(A2,Sheet1,sum(!b))

Answer (score 0):

please try the following:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B;F:F;"<>")
```

i hope this helps,

best - AB

Comment: Thanks for the respond, forgot to write, my range should contain all the sheet from d to infinity and from 2 to infinity

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try my favourite function, SUMPRODUCT :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN((F:F=$A$1)+(E:E=$A$1)+(D:D=$A$1))*B:B)
```

where $A$1 holds your lookup value, i.e. 7/5/2015 
Should work for both googlesheets and excel.

Didn't try hard, but maybe this works too (adapt "AA" to your last column):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D:AA=$A$1))*B:B)
```

You could even try to automatize the "AA" part with a `=MAX(1:1)` (what is the number of the last column in row 1?) coupled with the OFFSET function.

Explanations here:
[Sumproduct - Multiple criteria with "or"](http://www.sumproduct.com/thought/multiple-criteria)

Comment: Not sure I understand. My data is in sheet1 and my report is in sheet3. How can I choose the whole sheet1 (from d to infinity and from 2 to infinity)?

Comment: The `Offset()` function in Excel returns a cell or range of cells that is a specified number of rows and columns from a cell or range of cells. In your situation you could replace the `D:AA` part with `=OFFSET(sheet1!a1,1,3,ROWS(sheet1!A:A)-1,COLUMNS(sheet1!1:1)-3)` (your data has headings, so I began from D2). Attention: you encounter a problem of lack of ressources to evaluate the formula, see [the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333454/cant-insert-big-amount-of-data-to-worksheet). That is, imho **you can't do that my way**, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, my last formula is anyway NOT CORRECT because if you have your lookup value multiple times on the same row, it will sum the value from the column B multiple times.