# Is 64-bit Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel all I need?

Tags: c#

Background: An App to create an Excel file at a Server to hold large amount of data from SQL database. App has 32-bit `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DLL`. When data volume reaches certain size generate

> Insufficient Memory to continue the execution of the program.

This is due to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DLL` is [32-bit, addressable memory is limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333454/cant-insert-big-amount-of-data-to-worksheet).

Server = Win 2016 64-bit, has Office and Excel 2010 32-bit installed.

App = developed in VS 2017 (32-bit), [MS says to set `Any CPU` for build fits both 32 and 64-bit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/designing-and-creating-office-solutions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019).

Sample code to call Excel:

```
objExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
Workbook objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
Worksheet objWS = (Worksheet)objWB.ActiveSheet;
```

Is 64-bit `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DLL` all I need?

Comment: _"no Office or Excel installed"_ - the Interop assemblies are merely a translation layer from .NET to COM for automating Office. So there must be some part of Office running on the server. Going 64-bit (not only the assemblies, but also the Office installation) may solve this issue, but Office isn't meant to be automated on a server.

Comment: @CodeCaster Just corrected, server has 32-bit Excel installed. If my app carries 64-bit DLL, will it be incompatible server's local 32-bit Excel or still running in 32-bit space?

Comment: The interop dll has no specific bitness, it works just as well with a 64-bit version of Excel and your program as a 32-bit version.  Standard behavior for assemblies in C#.  So the question makes little sense.  If you make Excel run out of memory then using its 64-bit version is an easy workaround.

Comment: And *never* use Excel on a server, it is not made for that kind of usage.